# Unresolved reference iosMain Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform library that other KMM projects are using. I'm trying to build the iOS app of one of these KMM projects but first I need to publish the library binaries to a Maven repo.

When trying to build the iOS ARM 64 binaries it fails with `Unresolved reference` for one of the libraries I'm using. It only fails on gradle task `compileIosMainKotlinMetadata`, building the project works perfectly, but I cannot generate binaries because of this error.

This is my common multiplatform lib setup gradle: (`kotlin-multiplatform-lib-setup`)

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android {
        publishAllLibraryVariants()
    }
    ios()

    sourceSets {
         commonTest {
             dependencies {
                 implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                 implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
             }
         }

        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(31)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(23)
        targetSdkVersion(31)
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets {
        named("main") {
            manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
            res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my build.gradle.kts for the module I'm working on:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("kotlin-multiplatform-lib-setup")
    id("publish-setup")
}

publishing {
    publications.withType<MavenPublication> {
        groupId = "${Constants.artifactGroup}.architecture"
        artifactId = "core"
        version = Constants.artifactVersion
    }
}

kotlin {
    ios()

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.Badoo.reaktive)
                implementation(Deps.Badoo.coroutinesInterop)
                implementation(Deps.KotlinX.Coroutines.core)
                implementation(Deps.uuid)
            }
        }

        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.Badoo.reaktive)
                implementation(Deps.KotlinX.Coroutines.core)
                implementation(Deps.Badoo.reaktiveTesting)
            }
        }

        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.Badoo.reaktive)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tested to add with no result

```kotlin
kotlin {
  ios {
        binaries {
            framework { 
                export(Deps.Badoo.reaktive)
                transitiveExport = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Kotlin do  you use? Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: Are you building for a device or a simulator? Building for ARM simulator requires a separate target, add `iosSimulatorArm64()` along with `ios()`

Comment: @vanyochek Unfortunately, this is a company project so I can't provide a link. I'm using Kotlin 1.6.21

Comment: @PylypDukhov I'm building on a M1 Macbook, but I am unable to even build the app.  I am targetting my iPhone if that matters.

Comment: Try creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it can only contain your gradle setup

Answer (score 2):

The iosMain sourceset is not available by default in your module's build.gradle. So instead of adding `ios()` to sourcesets, add the three iOS configurations

```
iosX64()
iosArm64()
iosSimulatorArm64()
```

And instead of providing dependency for just iosMain, include all the configurations

```
iosMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation(Deps.Badoo.reaktive)
    }
}
```

Do this instead,

```
val iosX64Main by getting
val iosArm64Main by getting
val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
val iosMain by creating {
    dependsOn(commonMain)
    iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
    iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
    iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)

    dependencies {
        implementation(Deps.Badoo.reaktive)
    }
}
```

This way, it adds a new common dependency sourceset for handling all the iOS configurations.